# How to pass parameters to SQL script via Powershell on place of -inputfile param -serverinstance param\param -database param

Tags: powershell-4.0

invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\Duke\DBError.sql" -serverinstance "'$svr\$inst'" -database "test"

this is my powershell line of code i want to use param on place of hard code string pls help me is some know the solution

Comment: Have you googled? If yes, you should able to find a switch `-variable` (Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i got solution solution is as below

invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile $path -serverinstance $svr\$inst -database $DB